# how to change a div visibilty based on a checkbox value on separate view

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs

Many examples on how to do this when the elements are on the same view. My situation is, Modal-1 has a check box, Modal-2 has 2 check boxes, one that is unchecked and the other is checked. the unchecked check box is visible by default. If modal-1 check box is checked then I need to hide the visible check box and show the hidden one. I have to do it this way because there is issue with the print directive i have with check boxes. I'm not sure if ng-show would work better. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qeW0Tba81skmudw6JVOK?p=preview)

Modal-1

```
     <label style="margin-left:42px">Tax Exempt:</label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="currentItem.JobTaxExempt"  />
```

Modal-2

```
  <label style="margin-left:120px">
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <input style="display:none;" type="checkbox" checked />
      &nbsp;Tax&nbsp;Exempt
  </label>
```

Comment: not 100% clear what your issue is but it looks like you will need a service to share the data across multiple controllers

Comment: Do the modals have the same Scope?

Comment: Yes, both on same controller

Comment: I am guessing when I open the second modal a new instance of the controller?

Comment: modal-2 html has ng-controller in markup, even if same name would be different instances

Comment: i just noticed that. I used a previous plunker example for this. my modal setup does not have any controller markup. I do have rootscope setup for something else. could I use that for this ?